# How to represent an integer as a set of digits 0-9

Tags: functions

Assume $n, k \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $n$ is comprised of $k$ digits.

We then define a function $F$ where $$F(n) = A$$ and $$A = \begin{Bmatrix}a_1, a_2, .., a_i, .., a_k\end{Bmatrix}$$

s.t.

$$ \bigcup_{i=1}^{k}{\: a_i} \: = \: n $$

where, in this case, $a_i$ is being treated as the string (textual) representation of the digit, to then "combine" back into $n$. I don't know how else to define this part, so I apologize if this part is unclear.

Example: $$F(1024) = \begin{Bmatrix} 1,&0,&2,&4 \end{Bmatrix}$$

Essentially, what I'm trying to do is take an integer and assign an index to each of its digits, to then be able to directly reference certain digits and peform various operations on them. I thought that representing $n$ as a set of single digit integers, where the index of the single digit integer within $n$ is the same index it would have within the "set form" of $n$, would accomplish this, but I'm really in unchartered waters here.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you just trying to split a number into its digits?

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that I am, to then perform operations on those digits within the set.

Comment: $\bigcup_{i=1}^{k}{\: a_i} =  n$ is somewhat strange. $n$ you defined is a number rather than a set.

Comment: From your definition, is this right for $F(111) = \{1\}$?

Comment: @Ryan $F(111) = \begin{Bmatrix}1,&1,&1 \end{Bmatrix}$

Comment: So, it is not a set. Maybe you can use sequence instead.

Comment: @Charles what is your purpose for representing the digits of a number? Is it mathematical or programming? If it is programming you can use an approach like the one in quasi's answer. If it is mathematical you can just say $F(x)$ is defined to be the sequence/multiset/set/set-of-sets/etc consisting of the digits of $x$ represented in base 10. You don't need to specify how it is done.

Comment: @Χpẘ Ultimately, it's a combination of both; however, for the sake of this post, it's mathematical.

Comment: @Charles In that case just define it to be whatever mathematical structure u want *that has the properties you need*. The properties you probably need are an index and a one to one relationship between the members of the structure and the digits of the number. If you pick a structure that has indexing "built in", like a sequence, you don't have to worry about keeping which digit (ones digit, tens digits, etc.) a particular element is associated with. On the other hand if you use a set-like structure without a built-in index, each element must contain both the digit value and which digit it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want is to perform an operation on each digit, you don't need to build the sequence of digits. Instead, just extract each digit, one at a time, and perform the operation on the digit, without storing it.

The following pseudocode will accomplish the task . . .

```
    m = n
    while m > 0 do
        d = m mod 10
        [do something with d]
        m = (m-d)/10
    end do
```

Of course, you *can* store the digits in a list, if you want.

Note: The above code retrieves the digits from right to left (i.e., from low order to high order).

If instead, you want a "formula" for a function $f$, defined for all positive integers $n$, such that $f(n)$ is the sequence of decimal digits of $n$ (in left-to-right order), then $f$ can defined as
\begin{align*}
f(n) &= (d_1,...,d_j)\\[6pt]
&\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
\text{where}\\[6pt]
j &= 1+\left\lfloor\log_{10}(n)\right\rfloor\\[4pt]
d_i &=\left\lfloor\frac{n}{10^{j-i}}\right\rfloor\;\text{mod}\;10,
\;\;\text{for $1 \le i \le j$}\\[8pt]
&\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
\text{Thus, for example, if $n=6505$, then}\\[8pt]
j &= 1+\left\lfloor\log_{10}(6505)\right\rfloor=4\\[4pt]
d_1 &
= \left\lfloor\frac{6505}{10^3}\right\rfloor\;\text{mod}\;10 
= 6\;\text{mod}\;10
= 6\\[4pt]
d_2 &
= \left\lfloor\frac{6505}{10^2}\right\rfloor\;\text{mod}\;10 
= 65\;\text{mod}\;10
= 5\\[4pt]
d_3 &
= \left\lfloor\frac{6505}{10^1}\right\rfloor\;\text{mod}\;10 
= 650\;\text{mod}\;10
= 0\\[4pt]
d_4 &
= \left\lfloor\frac{6505}{10^0}\right\rfloor\;\text{mod}\;10 
= 6505\;\text{mod}\;10
= 5\\[6pt]
&\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
\text{hence}\\[6pt]
f(6505) &= (6,5,0,5)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

You can show that given any $a \in \mathbb{N}$ with $a \neq 0, 1$, that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists unique $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and unique $a_0, \dots, a_m$ with $0 \leq a_m < a$ such that $n = \sum_{i = 0}^m a_ma^i$. Digits are just a special case of this, for $a = 10$.

In fact, this is true in the far more general situation of the ordinals; just replace the first and second $\mathbb{N}$ with "the class of all ordinals".